# How to save data from spark to Google cloud platform?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

I will extract the data from oracle database through Spark, and then I want to store this data from spark to any storage in Google cloud platform. Is it possible? Data size is around 10TB.

Comment: are you using gcp free tier?

Comment: How much data is the original data in Oracle?  Is it also 10TB?  Is there a place that you want to run Spark?  Perhaps on premises or in GCP?  What do you see as your primary problem?  Is this a one-time transformation from your Oracle data or do you plan on running this again in the future?  Are you willing to spend on dedicated high-bandwidth networking between on-premises and GCP?  Where is your Oracle database today?  Are you willing to spend on a transfer appliance to load your data locally and ship it to Google?

Comment: Original data in oracle is 10 TB. I will use Spark from DataProc (in GCP). Will do cleansing in dataprep (in GCP) and then store it to big query finally. Willing to spend on bandwidth, but not want CSV copying options. Oracle is on premise. Not want to use transfer appliance ship. Next month there is to again update the incremental data to above same procedure. Next month data will be 14TB.  At the last after this batch data transfer, will have to do real time data processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Spark in GCP using Qubole. There are also "Data Connectors" available which will allow you to integrate with Oracle and other RDBMS systems.

A general flow could look like:
- Run a spark job using JDBC to read from Oracle
- Perform any necessary processing
- Write the data back out to GCS or BigQuery

Ref: https://www.qubole.com/blog/technical-overview-of-qubole-on-gcp/
and https://docs-gcp.qubole.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cloud storage connector with apache-spark**, here is the link through it which might help you can refer to it.

[Google cloud connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/gcs-connector-spark-tutorial)

Comment: In Google cloud connector, here copying options is used. Which do not want to use. If copying has to do, then we can export data to CSV from oracle database and store upload in cloud storage. No copying options to use.

Comment: No GCP free tier.